# windows 7 32 bit driver for HP Deskjet 825c

Tags: windows-7

After install of Windows 7 32 bit the drivers for HP Deskjet 825c are unavailable from HP or Microsoft.  Is there a generic driver solution that can be loaded?

Answer (score 2):

If you run Windows Update, it should return the Deskjet 830C/832C  drivers. They have been known to work. If they don't return under Windows Update, post back.

Answer (score 2):

Use the HP Deskjet 830c/832c driver. You will have to manually add the printer. Here is how:

1. *Start, Control Panel, Devices and Printers*
2. Click *Add a printer*
3. Click *Add a local printer*
4. Selct *Use an existing port*
5. In the drop down list select *USB001* or *002* or *003*, whichever appears. It should say "(Virtual printer port for USB)"
6. Click *Next*
7. On the *Install the printer driver screen*, under *Manufacturer* select *HP*
8. Under *printers* select *HP DeskJet 830C/832C*
9. Click *Next*
10. If prompted for "Which version of the driver do you want to use?" select "Use the driver that is currently installed." and click *Next*
11. Type a name for the printer by printer name.
12. Click *Next*
13. If you want other computers on your network to be able to share this printer select "Share this printer..." and click *Next*.
14. Click *Print a test page*.
15. Click *Finish*.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the HP site and install the XP drivers. A quick Google search shows that people are reporting this as [working](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/0b01e839-4290-415a-8a79-9fa3b3eb080b/). Someone on social.technet describes a method to get it working if it still doesn't work:

> If it does not work on your issue, I'd suggest you installing the XP driver in Compatibility mode. Remove and rescan that hardware device in Device Manager, right-click on the driver executable/installer file -> Properties and select the Compatibility tab; click the checkbox before Run this program in Compatibility mode for option and select Windows XP in the list-down box; then try installing the device driver. In addition, you can use the Windows Vista driver for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT install the XP Drivers, HP has a document on how to install the printer, the driver is already integrated into Windows 7.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01874792&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=59862&sw_lang=&os=4062&key=null&site=null

Comment: This driver is not integrated into Windows 7. I checked on Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Starter.

Comment: You are correct =)